# Map of methods from different classes in C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, dictionary, methods

I'm working on mapping keyboard input to functions. I've done significant portion of it, but now I need to bind a string to a function so that when the key referenced to that string is pressed, it will be called.

I know I can use
template 
void BindStringToAction(std::string key, T* obj, R (T::*methodPointer)(float));

But the issue is storing it for continued use. These methods could have a base class and could all have the same input (float) and return type (void) but storing them in a map requires a set ClassName.

So essentially the question is how do i store a map of a string and method pointer, the latter of which could be in any class.

Unreal does the same thing but I can't find an implementation or similar information. I found std::function but that also relies on class names that vary and therefore I can't make a map for it.

Comment: You could write a Builder to construct the map, then store a list of, say, `pair<string, string>` which would serve as a set of instructions to the Builder. Would that be adequate?

Comment: There's no such thing as a "method pointer to any class", in C++. What you're asking for is impossible. You'll have to figure out a different way to accomplish whatever you're trying to accomplish. XY problem.

Comment: `std::function<void(float)> f = [=](float val) { obj->methodPointer(val); };`. Now store that in `std::map<std::string, std::function<void(float)>>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++11, you can use lambdas to wrap your callbacks functions/methods. For example:

```
struct A {
    void callback(float in) {
        std::cout << "A : " << in << std::endl;
    }
};

struct B {
    void callback(float in) {
        std::cout << "B : " << in << std::endl;
    }
};

int main() {
    A a;
    B b;
    std::map<std::string, std::function<void(float)>> callbacks;
    callbacks["A"] = [&a](float in){a.callback(in);};
    callbacks["B"] = [&b](float in){b.callback(in);};

    callbacks["A"](3.14);
    callbacks["B"](42.);
}
```

The output is:

```
A : 3.14
B : 42
```

This way it doesn't matter if your callback is a function, a method or a lambda. I use this system for something similar to what you are doing and it works just fine.

Comment: Is it possible to convert a function so other developers don't need to use lambdas? Something like:

template <typename T, typename R>
void write(T* obj, R(T::*methodPointer)(float)) {
 std::function<void(float)> a = [obj](float in) { methodPointer(in); };
 a(1);
}

Comment: Well since lambdas are easy to use and pretty common nowadays I strongly suggest that you and the developers you work with to get use to them. They are very handy and you will find a lot of cases where using them will simplify your code